# Update variable when react state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to update a variable when the `scores` state changes. At the moment I have a function inside a `useEffect` hook which calculate the sum of the scores array and updates the global totalScore variable. For some reason the `totalScore` variable doesn't seem to be updating and displaying correctly on the screen - it just stays at 0.

```
let totalScore = 0
const [scores, setScores] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  scores.forEach((score) => {
    totalScore += score
  }
}, [scores])

return (
  <>
    <p>{totalScore}</p>
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

> For some reason the totalScore variable doesn't seem to be updating
> and displaying correctly on the screen - it just stays at 0.

This is because the `useEffect` hook runs *after* the component has rendered to the DOM. The `totalScore` variable was updated, but React needs another rerender to get it to the DOM.

## Suggested Solution

Since it's derived "state" from the `scores` state, it would be better to just compute the `totalScore` from the `scores` state in the component render.

```
const [scores, setScores] = useState([]);

const totalScore = scores.reduce((total, score) => score + total, 0);

return (
  <>
    <p>{totalScore}</p>
  </>
);
```

You can memoize `totalScore` with the `useMemo` hook if necessary.

```
const totalScore = useMemo(() => {
  return scores.reduce((total, score) => score + total, 0);
}, [scores]);
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, that worked a treat!  I've got a different problem now which expands on this:
I have two arrays in state, array A and array B. I want to calculate the (sum of array A - sum of array B) and display that value on the screen as the arrays/state changes. Another small trick to this is that I don't want to calculate the value if the arrays are of different length. If the arrays are of different length, I want to keep the previous value displayed on the screen. Do I need to store the calculated value in state in order to do that?

Comment: @DanielEvans Yes, for this I believe you'll want to use a `useState`|`useEffect` combo since you now want to ***conditionally*** update a total, and in order to do this the `totalScore` value needs to be promoted to local state so it can persist rerender cycles when you ***don't*** update it. Does this make sense?

Answer (score -1):

You need to have `totalScore` in your state for it to get updated.

```
const [totalScore, setTotalScore] = useState(0)
const [scores, setScores] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
   let ts = 0;
   scores.forEach((score) => {
      ts += score
   }
   setTotalScore(ts);
}, [scores])
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to have totalScore in state, in fact if its a derived value from other state values, I would suggest to _not_ store it in state, and to calculate during each render, `const totalScore = scores.reduce(sumFn, 0)` and if its intensive, wrap it with `useMemo` for memoization